# Как добавить в масссив inputa, данные?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Как добавить в масссив inputa, данные?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mass_dev" class="zakazi_inp" name="DevelopmenMass[mass_dev][1]" value="1">
```

`[mass_dev]` - Как сюда добавит даные, но не в виде еще одного массива?

Как просто в HTML, это сделать, и как это сделать в JS?

Comment: какие данные можно добавить в [mass_dev] ? Это индекс массива и все это DevelopmenMass[mass_dev][1] будет равно значению из value при сабмите формы.

Comment: @gilo1212, уберите `[1]`

Comment: html - это вам не angular, name не является указателем на модель данных, а всего лишь паттерном для структуры данных при отправке формы. технически до срабатывания события submit DevelopmenMass[mass_dev] еще не существует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы добавить данные в массив mass_dev, нужно данные отправить так:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mass_dev" class="zakazi_inp" name="mass_dev[]" value="1">
```

если вы хотите, чтобы данные были под каким-то конкретным id в массиве, то задайте этот id в [], например: `name="mass_dev[hello]"` , в этом случае, на стороне сервера будет `$_POST['mass_dev']['hello']` (если данные отправлены методом $_POST).